# DIVs after a float left element on explorer appears after that element (not underneath)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, css-float

Why does the 2 boxes are side by side in IE7 while "b" is underneath "a" on other browsers (where it should be)?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.a { float:left; width:100px; height:50px; background-color:#CCC; }
.b { width:75px; height:75px; background-color:#F00; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use the try-it editor for a live preview (copy-paste my code): http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float4

**EDIT: I want a fix on IE so it does the same thing as FF, Chrome, Safari, etc**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about the [The IE Float Model Problem](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatmodel.html)

Comment: Since this is really what's happening, and since there's no workaround, I took another approach. Still this answers my question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add [`clear`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_class_clear.asp) to `b` to force it to appear under `a` in all browsers:

```
.b { clear: both; width:75px; height:75px; background-color:#F00; }
```

Comment: I want it underneath (not under/another line) like it should be

Answer (score 1):

If you want elements underneath, why even use float? Use `display:block` instead, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Don't ask why ;) Seriously, this is the simplest sample I could come up with. And IE clearly have a display problem.. I want a IE fix